# Why can't I use the turtle GIU for python anymore?

Tags: python, error-handling, version-control, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I have used pycharm to run python code, and I want to use the GUI => The turtle, and the screen to run it, but it keeps on giving me errors or a black screen. What do I do? The same happens with VSC... Idk really know how this works on trinket.io and don't want to use it there either.

Is this a problem with my code?

Here's the code I input: (I asked an AI for help on the os part with the tk silence deprecation and all that)

```
import os
os.environ["TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION"] = "1"

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pendown()
turtle.pencolor("red")
turtle.forward(100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

It either showed me a black screen on pycharm or nothing at all and said it was outdated on VSC.

Comment: What OS are you on? Version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new prosjekt in pycharm and pasted your code:

[Result for running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLWzd.png)

As you can see the code works fine.
Worst case make a new prosjekt in pycharm.
If it helps I had these python interpreter's:

pip

setuptools

wheel

 settings > YOUR_PROJECT_NAME > Python interpreter
(I'm using Windows 11)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).